# Python3: How to pass variable names constructed by iterator in a for loop

Tags: python, user-interface, for-loop, parameter-passing, python-3.5

Using guizero to place buttons for a GUI in Python3.

I have multiple buttons, named:
sound_button_01
sound_button_02
sound_button_03, etc.

These are defined in the standard way, and work without problems.

I want to iterate through these buttons with a for loop and change the background color (e.g., sound_button_01.bg = "red") of each one.

This works when I call my color change function with the full variable name:

```
def change_color(button_name)
    button_name.bg = "red"
    return

[main code]

change_color(sound_button_01)
```

This works flawlessly. But, when I try to iterate with the i variable:

```
[same def as above]

[main program starts]
for i in range (1,3):
    target_button = ("sound_button_0") + str (i)
    change_color(target_button)
[for loop ends]
```

I get an error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bg'.

So there is probably some dead simple way to convert the string "target_button" variable into something that I can pass to the function. But darned if I can figure out what it is....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you iterate on a list of the buttons? Like:

```
for button in [sound_button_01, sound_button_02, sound_button_03]:
    change_color(button)
```

Also, for concision and more dynamic code, you could store the buttons in a list, so the iteration become:

```
for button in sound_buttons:
    change_color(button)
```

Comment: Bingo!

If you make this list button_list = [button_01,button_02,button_03]

Then print (button_list) gives you:

[PushButton] object with text "Button 1", [PushButton] object with text "Button 2], etc.

Trying to create such a list iterating just gives you ['button_01','button_02'] which is back to the same problem.

Thanks! Still a bit clunky, but works.